# How does osmdroid's CopyrightOverlay.setCopyrightNotice() work?

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I added a copyright notice to my map like this:

```
/* add copyright overlay */
val copyrightOverlay = CopyrightOverlay(this)
copyrightOverlay.setCopyrightNotice("This doesn't do anything :(")
mapView.overlays.add(copyrightOverlay)
```

The [documentation](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/CopyrightOverlay.html#setCopyrightNotice-java.lang.String-) doesn't mention what `setCopyrightNotice(String pCopyrightNotice)` is supposed to do.

I expected it to somehow change the text of the copyright overlay. But as shown in the screenshot below, the overlay still says `© OpenStreetMap contributors`

Does anyone know how this method is supposed to be used? Did I miss anything?

[image: screenshot]

(the reason I tried to edit the notice was to find a way to make donations to OSM, similarly to the overlay at [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the [source code](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/473046516b73f16b9e4709500fd2171052d7ae9e/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/CopyrightOverlay.java) :  since it's open source.

There we can see that setter should set the text:

```
public void setCopyrightNotice(final String pCopyrightNotice) {
        mCopyrightNotice = pCopyrightNotice;
}
```

But we can also see that the draw method gets the copyright notice from tile source:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView map, boolean shadow) {
    setCopyrightNotice(map.getTileProvider().getTileSource().getCopyrightNotice());  
    draw(canvas, map.getProjection());
}
```

This practically overrides the value you set every time the overlay is drawn.

I kind of think this is a mistake in the API. The `setCopyrightNotice` method shouldn't be public, that's just confusing.

I would suggest to implement your own copyright notice overaly - you can fallow the original source and reproduce the code exactly how you want it to be.